# best way to save a period of time in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, time

I was creating a mysql Database to store hockey game scoring summaries and was wondering what would be the most efficient way to store the time of a goal/penalty occurs(20 min in a period) in the database.

I was thinking of using the int type and convert the value into min:sec.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You could use two different columns each one for minutes and seconds respectively.

Comment: 1 int covers all possibilities including OT

Comment: It seems to me that you could just store a TIME datatype. Time in ice hockey appears to be so tightly regulated that if someone scores in th 21st minute, then it must be the 1st minute of the 2nd period. If someone scores in the 66th minute, then it must be the 1st minute of the 2nd overtime period.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the best way so save a time is to use a timestamp because it's very easy to use (especially using PHP) and MySQL loves it !

Answer (score 0):

A common technique is to store the value in seconds using an integer field. Then when displaying the time you divid by minutes / hours to give a human readable version (i.e. (HH:MM:SS). Since MySQL5.5 there's even a handy function [sec_to_time()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) that does this for you:

```
mysql> SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(time)

Outputs:
--> '00:12:34'
```